# Is my error due to an absolute path issue?

Tags: python, pandas, python-os

I am trying to create a variable that stores a folder within the directory I am working in called TimeSeries. After that, I am trying to read each file in TimeSeries. Apparently, my error stems from `df = pd.read_csv(f)` being a relative path instead of an absolute path. However, I can't confirm this, as when I check `isabs(direct)`, I get back True. I do know that the error is about that specific line, I just don't know what it is.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

direct = os.path.abspath('TimeSeries')


for f in direct:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = df.replace(np.nan, 'Other', regex=True)
    if df.columns[0] == ['FIPS']:
        print(df.columns)
        df = df.drop(['FIPS', 'Last_Update', 'Lat', 'Long_'], axis=1)
        df = df.rename(columns={'Admin2': 'County',
                                'Province_State': 'State',
                                'Country_Region': 'Country',
                                'Combined_Key': 'City'})
        df.to_csv(f)
    elif df.columns[0] == ['Province/State']:
        print(df.columns)
        df = df.drop(['Last Update'], axis=1)
        df = df.rename(columns={'Province/State': 'State',
                                'Country/Region': 'Country'})
        df.to_csv(f)
    else:
        pass
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Corona Stats/Corona.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File C does not exist: 'C'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is what happens when I print direct.

```
C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Corona Stats\TimeSeries
```

Comment: `C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Corona Stats\TimeSeries`

Comment: you should include it in the question.

Comment: Don't iterate over for loop, `for f in direct:` the bug is over here. Since `os.path.abspath()` returns your path is `str` type and you are iterating over a string in the for loop.

Comment: So, then, what do I do? I am desperate at this point.

Comment: If you want to iterate over files in the directory, use `files = os.listdir(direct)` then iterate over `files` variable.

Comment: If you mean like `for item in os.listdir(direct):` that's covered in the answer below resulting in `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File 01-22-2020.csv does not exist: '01-22-2020.csv'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC: Try:

```
source = "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Corona Stats/TimeSeries"
for filename in os.listdir(source):
    filepath = os.path.join(source, filename)
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        continue

    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    df = df.replace(np.nan, 'Other', regex=True)
    if df.columns[0] == 'FIPS':
        print(df.columns)
        df = df.drop(['FIPS', 'Last_Update', 'Lat', 'Long_'], axis=1)
        df = df.rename(columns={'Admin2': 'County',
                                'Province_State': 'State',
                                'Country_Region': 'Country',
                                'Combined_Key': 'City'})
        df.to_csv(filepath)
    elif df.columns[0] == 'Province/State':
        print(df.columns)
        df = df.drop(['Last Update'], axis=1)
        df = df.rename(columns={'Province/State': 'State',
                                'Country/Region': 'Country'})
        df.to_csv(filepath)
```

Comment: This returns `exit code 0` with no changes to any file.

Comment: Replace `df.columns[0] == ['FIPS']` with `df.columns[0] == 'FIPS'` and `df.columns[0] == ['Province/State']` with `df.columns[0] == 'Province/State'`

Answer (score 1):

With python or pandas when you use read_csv or pd.read_csv, both of them look into current working directory, by default where the python process have started. So you need to use os module to chdir() and take it from there.

```
import pandas as pd 
import os
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("<PATH TO DIRECTORY>")
print(os.getcwd())
df = pd.read_csv('<The Filename You want to read>')
print(df.head())
```

Comment: How do I put in the path to directory? `C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Corona Stats\TimeSeries` is giving me invalid escape sequence.

Comment: You need to add double \\ instead of a Single \ while passing a path in python

Comment: `os.chdir('<C:\\Users\\USER\\PycharmProjects\\Corona Stats\\TimeSeries>')` results in: `OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<C:\\Users\\USER\\PycharmProjects\\Corona Stats\\TimeSeries>'`

Comment: You dont need to add the < > Brackets in the path, i had mentioned that as a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Here you're iterating over *EACH* letter in the path:

```
direct = 'C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Corona Stats/TimeSeries'

for f in direct:
    ...
```

If you want to get the files in the directory you should use something like:

```
for item in os.listdir(direct):
    ...
```

Personally I would use `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

direct = Path('C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Corona Stats/TimeSeries')

for item in direct.glob('*'):
    ...
```

Comment: `for item in os.listdir(direct):` produces: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File 01-22-2020.csv does not exist: '01-22-2020.csv'` which is an issue I have already run into.

Comment: `glob` just returns exit code 0 with no changes to any of the files.

Comment: What is `Timeseries`? A directory?  Where is it?